# Sumproduct dates

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet worksheet called “ISO Procedure Master List” where the date a procedure is requested is in **`column G (Format m/dd/yyyy).`**

In column H the date the procedure is completed is entered. Column H uses the same date format but may contain blanks (procedure not completed yet).

There are currently 67 rows of information in the spreadsheet that span from 2011 to 2015 and that number will continue to grow.

**QUESTION**, I would like to get the average time (in days) it took from a procedure request **`(column G)`** to the completion of procedure **`(column H)`** for all of the procedures requested in a given year.

In other words the average (in days) time it took to complete procedures in a given year.

This answer will be in a cell **`C34`** in the same workbook but a different worksheet called **`“ISO Matrix”`**. (This information probably does not matter but I thought I would add I just in case)

I have tried several Sumproduct variations with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. Dates in columns G and H are dates, not text string,
2. Data start in row 2, using row 1 for headings.
3. For convenience, I assume you have named the ranges you wish to average requestDate and completeDate
4. You wish do ommit the rows where the procedure is not finished from the average calculation.

After naming your ranges, input the following formula into C34 on "ISO Matrix" tab:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(completeDate<>"";completeDate-requestDate))
```

This is an array formula, so when normally pressing enter, remember to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead. When highlighting the cell, it will then look like this:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(completeDate<>"";completeDate-requestDate))}
```

NOTE: My language pack uses ; as formula separator, so if you language uses , instead, change the formula to:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(completeDate<>"",completeDate-requestDate))
```

---

EDIT: So, I didn't catch that you needed to average by year. In line with my recent formula, it could be update to suit your request.

```
=AVERAGE(IF(completeDate<>"";IF(YEAR(requestDate)=A15;completeDate-requestDate)))
```

where A15 holds the year you are interested in. I tried it with an AND in the first IF instead of two IFs, but that did not seem to work. Mind you, you might still need to change ; to , and you also need CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER for this one.

You could also add the code below, to handle the case where you test a year that is not present in the list:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(completeDate<>"";IF(YEAR(requestDate)=A15;completeDate-requestDate)));"No such year")
```

...or something like that

Comment: @carl5859 Use `=IsNumber(G3)` to test if a cell is numeric (dates are numeric). Use `=IsText(G3)` to test if a cell is a text string.

Comment: - The dates are numeric

Comment: your assumptions are correct
The worksheet the formula is located (Cell C34) is called "ISO Matrix". The worksheet the dates are located (rows G&H) is "ISO Procedure Master List". tried the above formula and got "#Name". I catered it to the master list worksheet got "#Name". 
example
=AVERAGE(IF('ISO Procedure Master List'!completeDate<>"",'ISO Procedure Master List'!completeDate-A1:A5))
example of unsuccessful formula.
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER('ISO Procedure Master List'!H:H),'ISO Procedure Master List'!H:H-'ISO Procedure Master List'!G:G,0))/COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER('ISO Procedure Master List'!H:H),1,"X"))

Comment: This formula almost worked but I could not get it to be year specific. This averaged the entire columns. 

=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER('ISO Procedure Master List'!H:H),'ISO Procedure Master List'!H:H-'ISO Procedure Master List'!G:G,0))/COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER('ISO Procedure Master List'!H:H),1,"X"))

Comment: Don't know exactly how this happened, but there was an error in my formula. You were of course supposed to use the the named range requestDate instead of A1:A5, so if you started at line 2 as in my suggestion, it will go wrong with the previous formulas. They are now corrected. Make sure that completeDate and requestDate in your formula exactly match your named ranges.

Comment: Mind you, it has been tested and works on my computer, if you have the named ranges correct in both formula and in the sheet, and remember to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just ENTER, it should work. Note that you do not need to use the same named ranges as I, just make sure they match. And make the named ranges workbook wide and skip the reference to sheet name in the formula.

Comment: Gudal, Your formula worked well. It worked the same as the formula I came up with but is less complicated. =SUM(IF(ISNUMBER('ISO Procedure Master List'!H:H),'ISO Procedure Master List'!H:H-'ISO Procedure Master List'!G:G,0))/COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER('ISO Procedure Master List'!H:H),1,"X")). The issue I am having with my formula and the one you gave me is it is not date specific. Currently it averages the full columns. I need it to average a specific year like '2011'

Comment: Gudal, I figured out the formula. Your help was instrumental in helping me figure it out. Here is the formula that works              =SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(requestDate)=2011),--(completeDate<>0),(completeDate)-(requestDate))/SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(requestDate)=2011),--(completeDate<>0))

Comment: Ahh. I did not know manage to catch the fact that you needed  by year. I have updated my formula in the answer to match that problem, if you wanted one less complicated.